# UI Theme Detection: Unit test code coverage

Tags: unit-test, lightning-experience, code-coverage, salesforce-classic

Since Winter '16, we have had [the ability](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html) to add conditional logic to our Apex controllers and Visualforce pages based on the UI theme the user is currently working with (i.e. Classic vs. Lightning Experience vs. the Salesforce Mobile App).

For example:

```java
String theme = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
if (theme == 'Theme2' || theme == 'Theme3') { // Salesforce Classic
    // do something
} else if (theme == 'Theme4d') { // Lightning Experience
    // do something else
}
```

If I want to get 100% coverage with my unit tests, I need to create a user and set the UI theme for that user.  Ideally I would like to avoid any dependencies on Profile settings, since admins are likely to toggle these.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer , have you look into this? If you already have the answer let me know.